# What is the name of the following partial differential operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the name of the following partial differential operator?

$$\sum_{|\alpha| \leq n} a_\alpha (\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^\alpha$$

Thank you!

Comment: What are the coefficients $a_{\alpha}$?

Comment: Probably $L$. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It does not have a particular name.

It is the general form of a *linear partial differential operator of order $n$*.

Comment: if there exists $a_\alpha$ where $|\alpha|=n$ and $a_\alpha\neq0$